# monodevelop system.drawing can not be found

Tags: monodevelop, system.drawing

Recently, I downloaded mono. I can not use:

```
using System.Drawing
```

It just shows me an error. Are there any additional packages that i need to download, or is it just a bug ? Went to add-in manager and i have all packages installed.

this is what i got from error list:

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Drawing' does not exist in
>   the namespace`System'. Are you missing `System.Drawing' assembly
>   reference? (CS0234)

Comment: Does your project actually reference `System.Drawing.dll`?

Comment: As @O.R.Mapper mentioned, in the references folder you need a reference to the dll. Right clicking on project and hitting add references should do it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a reference to the System.Drawing libraries. If you're using MonoDevelop, right click `Preferences` -> `Edit References`, and under `Packages` make sure that "System.Drawing" is checked.

Comment: What about if you're not using a GUI? Is there something I can edit in the `csproj` file?